How can I show only one alert for multiple deletions in angular?
I have a code like this =>
return next.handle(req).pipe(
  map((response: any) => {
    if ( req.method !== "GET" && response instanceof HttpResponse && response.status === 200) {
      this.alertService.showSuccessAlert();
    }
  return response;
}),

I want to show only one alert in multiple deletion. In the current scenario, one alert is shown per deleted item on the page, so this means a mess when 10 items are deleted.
I tried to solve by creating a boolean variable but it didn't work.
EDIT:
my component =>
multipleDeleteCategory() { 
  const selectedCategories = this.myForm.value.selectedCategory;
   if (selectedCategories && selectedCategories.length > 0) { 
    selectedCategories.forEach((category: Category) => { 
      this.categoryService.deleteCategory(category.id).subscribe(() => { 
        this.categories = this.categories.filter(cat => cat.id !== category.id); 
      }); 
    }); 
  } 
}

Alert Service =>
public showSuccessAlert(): void { 
  this.toastrService.success('Your transaction has been completed', 'Success:', this.getAlert()); }


How do you execute this deletion functionality? Is it a single function executed in a loop?

@KadirErsezer please share the library your using to show the alert, if possible the code for showSuccessAlert and more detials on alert service!

@NarenMurali Sure. I'm using ngx-toastr library for notifications. Here is the code for showSuccessAlert in Alert Service =>
public showSuccessAlert(): void {
this.toastrService.success('Your transaction has been completed', 'Success:', this.getAlert());
}

@mat.hudak This is the deletion function i used in my component =>
multipleDeleteCategory() { const selectedCategories = this.myForm.value.selectedCategory; if (selectedCategories && selectedCategories.length > 0) { selectedCategories.forEach((category: Category) => { this.categoryService.deleteCategory(category.id).subscribe(() => { this.categories = this.categories.filter(cat => cat.id !== category.id); }); }); } }
The first code I shared was the first condition statement of global error handling in my interceptor file.

@KadirErsezer Can you share the code that you have tried for this statement I tried to solve by creating a boolean variable but it didn't work.

@YashMaheshwari Sure, it was like this => return next.handle(req).pipe(
map((response: any) => {
if (req.method !== "GET" && response instanceof HttpResponse && response.status === 200) {
if (response.body && Array.isArray(response.body)) {
const deletedItemCount = response.body.length;
if (deletedItemCount > 0) {
if (!this.alertService.successAlertShown) {
this.alertService.showSuccessAlert();
this.alertService.successAlertShown = true;
}
}
}
}
return response;
}),

I think you need to use this method findDuplicate to check if the message already exists, if it does not, then show the popup!
you code
public showSuccessAlert(): void { 
    if(!this.toastrService.findDuplicate('Your transaction has been completed', 'Success:', false, true)) {
        this.toastrService.success('Your transaction has been completed', 'Success:', this.getAlert()); 
    }
}

Below example, clicking success multiple times, will not work, if there is already a popup open!
Stackblitz Demo

findDuplicate source code
/**
   * Determines if toast message is already shown
   */
  findDuplicate(title = '', message = '', resetOnDuplicate: boolean, countDuplicates: boolean) {
    const { includeTitleDuplicates } = this.toastrConfig;

    for (const toast of this.toasts) {
      const hasDuplicateTitle = includeTitleDuplicates && toast.title === title;
      if ((!includeTitleDuplicates || hasDuplicateTitle) && toast.message === message) {
        toast.toastRef.onDuplicate(resetOnDuplicate, countDuplicates);
        return toast;
      }
    }

    return null;
  }


I made the necessary definitions and implemented the code, but it still didn't work.

@KadirErsezer only the first code block is needed, the second code block is just for reference,hope you used the first code block alone!

That's exactly what I did. But an error occurred => Expected 4 arguments, but got 2.ts(2554)
toastr.service.d.ts(62, 51): An argument for 'resetOnDuplicate' was not provided.
(method) ToastrService.findDuplicate(title: string, message: string, resetOnDuplicate: boolean, countDuplicates: boolean): ActiveToast
Determines if toast message is already shown                                             // And i fixed that line like this =>  if(!this.toastrService.findDuplicate('Your transaction has been completed', 'Success:', true, true) but unfortunately it still didn't work.

@KadirErsezer updated my answer try if(!this.toastrService.findDuplicate('Your transaction has been completed', 'Success:', false, true))

Unfortunately still same :(

@KadirErsezer check my working example, maybe try replicating the issue on the stackblitz! and share back!

Can you share your example link with me? I will get back to you after checking and applying it.

@KadirErsezer check this stackblitz

By the way, this problem was occurring because I went to the backend service one by one while performing multiple deletions. I learned that a special service needs to be written for multiple deletion. Still, i appreciate you taking the time ^^
